# Multiple client tables or large overall table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've recently taken over a project linking to a large MySQL DB that was originally designed many years ago and need some help.

Currently the DB has 5 tables per client that store their users information, transaction history, logs etc. However we currently have ~900 clients that have applied to use our services, with an average of 5 new clients applying weekly. So the DB has grown to nearly 5000 tables and ever increasing. Many of our clients do not end up using our services so their tables are all empty but still in the DB.

The original DB designer says it was created this way so if a table was ever compromised it would not reveal information on any other client.

As I'm redesigning the project in PHP I'm thinking of redesigning the DB to have an overall user, transaction history, log etc tables using the clients unique id to reference them.

Would this approach be correct or should the DB stay as is?

Could you see any possible security / performance concerns

Thanks for all your help

Comment: One thing you can do is institute a policy for how and when tire-kicker content is submarined, e.g., delete unused accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redesign the system to have just five tables, with a separate column identifying which client the row pertains to.  SQL handles large tables well, so you shouldn't have to worry about performance.  In fact, having many, many tables can be a hinderance to performance in many cases.

This has many advantages.  You will be able to optimize the table structures for all clients at once.  No more trying to add an index to 300 tables to meet some performance objective.  Managing the database, managing the tables, backing things up -- all of these should be easier with a single table.

You may find that the database even gets *smaller* in size.  This is because, on average, each of those thousands of tables has a half-paged filled at the end.  This will go from thousands of half-pages to just one.

The one downside is security.  It is easier to put security on tables than one rows in tables.  If this is a concern, you may need to think about these requirements.

Comment: Did you mean a separate **row** for each client?

Comment: Also to add to the security stance, I feel that the shear maintenance required to keep so many tables secure could possibly make them less secure than one large, centralized table.

Comment: @Elias . . . I mean a separate column, identifying the client in each table.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?  A downvote without an explanation just seems malicious.

Comment: A separate column for each client? I don't get it.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . You need to identify the client in one or more of the tables.  I don't know if such a column is needed in all the tables, but it would be needed in at least one.

Comment: Nope You've really lost me on this one.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying "each table will have a dedicated column per client". So if there are 5000 clients, there would be 5000 columns plus the columns for the table's purpose.

Comment: @JaredFarrish . . . No.  Each row in a table will be for a particular client and you probably need an identifier to say which client it is.

Comment: You need to revisit the first paragraph of your answer, as that's exactly what it sounds like you're suggesting: *with a separate column for each client.*

Comment: @JaredFarrish . . . Oh, that's sort of funny.  It was totally clear to me.  I changed the "for" to "identifying", which I think better expresses what I wanted to say.

Comment: Better yet, I've changed the first sentence to clarify that the extra column is for "identifying which client the row pertains to".

Answer (score 0):

This may just be a matter of taste, but I would find it far more natural - and thus maintainable - to store this information in as few tables as possible. Also most if not all database ORMs will be expecting a structure like this, and there is no reason to reinvent that wheel.

From the perspective of security, it sounds like this project could be described as a web app. Obviously I don't know the realities of the business logic you're dealing with, but it seems like regardless of the table permissions all access to the database would be via the code base, in which case the app itself needs full permissions for all tables - nullifying any advantage of keeping the tables separated.

If there is a compelling reason for the security measures - say, different services that feed data into the DB independently of the web app, I would still explore ways to handle that authentication at the application layer instead of at the database layer. It will be much easier to handle your security rules in that way. Instead of having rules set in 5000+ different places, a single security rule of 'only let a user view a row of data if their user id equals the user_id column" is far simpler, easier to understand, and therefore far more maintainable (and possibly *more* secure).

Different people approach databases in different ways. I am a web developer, so I view databases as the place to store my data and nothing more, as it's always a dedicated and generally single-purpose DB installation, and I handle all other logic at the application level. There are people who view databases as the application itself, who make far more extensive use of built-in security features for their massive, distributed, multi-user systems - but I honestly don't know enough about those scenarios to comment on exactly where that line should be drawn.